# $q service promise returning same data

Tags: angularjs

Below is the code where i have a **asyncService** that generates a random number and returns a promise object to the calling controller.I have created a deferred object which resolves if random number generated is >5 and rejects if number generated is <5.
Whenever i run this code, it always gets the same number.
Below is the code. See the console for message

```
angular.module("promisesModule",[])
.controller('MainCtrl',function(asyncService){
    this.startAsync = function(){
        asyncService.getRand().then(function(no){
            console.log("success and no is "+no);
        },function(no){
            console.log("failed and no is "+no);
        })
    }
})
.service('asyncService',function($q){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    this.getRand = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var no = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
            if(no >5){
                deferred.resolve(no);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(no);
            }
        },2000);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

Comment: [works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/7ru5f9dw/)

Comment: @scniro I originally upvoted your fiddle, but it only "proves" that it works because it is completely rerunning the entire fiddle every time.  It isn't consistent with the behavior the OP is experiencing and Anid's answer below correctly solves the problem.

Comment: ah yes nice observation I did indeed overlook that @DavidL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the declaration of the `deferred` variable into the `getRand` function. Otherwise, the same promise will be returned every time, which is what you're seeing.

```
.service('asyncService',function($q){
    this.getRand = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        setTimeout(function(){
            var no = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
            if(no >5){
                deferred.resolve(no);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(no);
            }
        },2000);

        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much..Completely missed that...The solution works   !